# Если ip зашёл первый раз - перенаправить его на другую страницу

Tags: jquery, ip, javascript

Задача такая: пользователь заходит на сайт первый раз и видит одну страницу (скажем /special). При повторном входе - он должен переходить на другую, уже на index.php
Как это сделать? Если есть возможность - огромная просьба поподробнее, т.к. я новичок в javascript...
Подобная задача (думаю что решается таким же методом) - новым материалам сайта в блоге присвоить класс, после их просмотра пользователем - класс убрать.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: >я новичок в javascript... Подобная задача (думаю что решается таким же методом) - новым материалам сайта в блоге присвоить класс, после их просмотра пользователем - класс убрать 

@greenmar - вы по моему не только в JavaScript новичок imho. "класс" это аттрибут тегов html на странице у клиента в сформированном браузером DOM а при каждом обновлении страницы DOM перестраивается! Почитайте что такое HTML а потом думайте о PHP :)

Comment: А в чём некорректность моего вопроса? Разве с помощью jquery нельзя присваивать классы элементам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На странице index.php:

```
if(document.cookie.indexOf('first_time')==-1){
 document.cookie='first_time=1';
 document.location.href='special.php';
}
```

Comment: Это не соответствует условию задачи. В заголовке написано про ip.

Comment: Ответ согласно тегам, которые поставил автор.

Comment: Если у клиента отключены куки и js то ему нечего делать у меня на сайте... Я думаю сейчас это единицы, у кого они отключены. За решение спасибо, работает! 
Ещё бы подумать как реализовать подсветку материалов...

Comment: @greenmar: например, у меня отключены cookies. Наверное, я не ваш клиент.

Comment: да любую статистику взять - обычно люди включают http://monster.gostats.ru/cookies.xml?id=4267